# Failing to use if statement with $i in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, if-statement, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently trying to follow a [tutorial](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/cakephp-tutorial-build-file-sharing-application) and I have reached the section where I use the if statement that will show me all the possible downloadable data that I have stored in a folder..

But the problem I'm having is with the if statements, it keeps telling me that I have an `Undefined variable: i`.. in this if statement

```
<p>Welcome <?php print $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name');
echo ' ';
echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout'));?> </p>
<dt> <?php if ($i % 2 == 0) echo $class; ?> <?php __('Download'); ?></dt>
<dd> <?php if ($i++ % 2 == 0) echo $class; ?> 
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Download', true), array('action' => 'download', $upload['Upload']['uploadID'])); ?>
</dd>
```

Here is the download function in the controller:

```
function download($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view'));
        }
        $this->Upload->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UploadsUser')));
        $upload = $this->Upload->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Upload.uploadID' => $id,
                'OR' => array(),
                                 )
                                                    ));
        if (!$upload) 
            {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view'));
            }
        $this->view = 'media';
        $filename = $upload['Upload']['fileName'];
        $this->set(array(
            'id' => $upload['Upload']['uploadID'],
            'name' => substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')),
            'extension' => substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1),
            'path' => APP . 'uploads' . DS,
            'download' => true,
        ));
    }
```

I also am aware that in if statements things should be =, == or ===, but for some reason in this tutorial he uses a % ? if you could also explain why that is used I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Is `$i` being used anywhere before these statements? If not, that would explain the `Undefined variable` error. As for the `%` you asked about, that is the modulus operator. It returns the remainder of the left side divided by the right side. In this case, it is dividing `$i` by 2 and returning the remainder, which will be a 1 or 0, effectively telling the code if `$i` is even or odd.

Comment: I quickly skimmed through the tutorial you are following, and noticed that view.ctp is being generated by `bake`, so not much on that page was helpful for this problem. It looks like the if statements you're having trouble with are meant to be inside of a loop. If you don't mind, could you show the code in view.ctp, or wherever you have this defined?

Comment: Hi @jonhopkins i added the whole view.ctp.. as you can see theres not much else there at the moment, what do you think the for each statement would be like?

Comment: The entire finished code for that tutorial is available at https://github.com/predominant/cakephp_linux_format/tree/master/fileshare
This particular file can be seen at https://github.com/predominant/cakephp_linux_format/blob/master/fileshare/views/uploads/view.ctp
It turns out he actually wants you to just define `$i` at the top of the file, and add a new block like the one you have above for each downloadable content. This could have been documented better in the tutorial, but at least he did provide the code..

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `$i` with some value, for example `$i = 10;` or `$i = 0;` but seem that `$i` is the result of a previous operation, check why is not defined.

% is the modulus (the rest of the division). More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Thanks m4t1t0 for the definition of %, $i is meant to represent the downloadable content.I have added the controller to see if that will help sort my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $i++ with ($i+1)

% is the rest of a division.

Ex: 5%2=1 (5/2=4 with the rest of 1)

Comment: `$i++` actually adds 1 to the variable, while `($i+1)` only returns the result of adding 1. Depending on usage, it might be desirable for the variable to actually be modified.

Comment: well what its meant to do is show all the available downloadable content, i can confirm that there are at least 3 items available to download

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$i` really is not defined so you get that message. You probably forgot to set it `$i = 0;`

The `%` operator is called [modulus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and returns the remainder of `$i/2`, so your expression is true when `$i` is even and false when `$i` is uneven.

In most if statements you just use `==` or the more strict `===`. Using `=` is most often an error and most IDEs warn you about it.

Comment: Thanks str for the definition of modulus, $i is meant to represent the downloadable content.I have added the controller to see if that will help sort my problem